# Updating a row using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a field in a table just after I have added a row in a different table. (The value is just to show that the row has been imported) I thought I was using the right code here, but the bool 'Imported' field isn't updated. Here is the relevant code:

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Details.Add(details);
    db.SaveChanges();
    newID = details.DetailsID;
    AccessRepository rep = new AccessRepository();
    AccessDetails detailUpdate = rep.GetByID(item.AccessDetailsTableID);
    detailUpdate.Imported = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The first SaveChanges call works, as I'm trying to add a new row, but not the second one.  It successfully retrieves the data back from the repository but just doesn't update the value.

Any ideas why it might not be working?

Thanks

Comment: Is your repository linking to the same context?

Comment: Yes, I just have the one context on the site.

Comment: I wonder why are you messing with repository inside the code block where you are already working with context itself. Also what you mean by one context on the site?

Comment: In your example, it can't be using the same context.You're creating a new context in the using statement, but your access repository is created inline, and you're not assigning the context to it.

Comment: That was right - I was confusing things with different contexts.  I thought db.SaveChanges would just work but didn't think using a context within the repository would affect it.  Working now - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your AccessRepository is using a different data context (db) to the one in scope (in your posted code)

You could try having a SaveChanges method in your AccessRepository which does the same but on the correct data context.

However, the issue with calling two saves is that you loss the single transaction benefits. So if those two updates are to be related you really should only call the SaveChanges once.

I would create an Add method and a Save method in your AccessRepository and then use something like this...

```
AccessRepository rep = new AccessRepository();
rep.Add(details);
AccessDetails detailUpdate = rep.GetByID(item.AccessDetailsTableID);
detailUpdate.Imported = true;
rep.Save();//this calls SaveChanges on a single data context
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Should you use newId in GetById() method?

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Details.Add(details);
    db.SaveChanges();
    newID = details.DetailsID;
    AccessRepository rep = new AccessRepository();
    AccessDetails detailUpdate = rep.GetByID(newID);
    detailUpdate.Imported = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: No - actually that gets used further down the function.  I actually should probably have removed that from the example.  This process is in the middle of a foreach loop so that is why I update using that ID.